# A simple program from MIT OpenCourseWare. I wonder what's wrong, please?

Tags: python

The exercise program is from MIT OpenCourseWare. It asks me to calculate how many months can a down payment is fulfilled, with three portion:1. investment. 2. Part of the salary. 3. The salary gains a semi-year raise: this should only happen after the 6th, 12th, 18th month, and so on.
Here is my work:

```
current_saving = 0

annual_salary = int(input("Enter your annual salary:"))
portion_saved = float(
input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:"))
total_cost = int(input("Enter the cost of your dream home:"))
semi_annual_raise = float(input("Enter the semi- annual raise, as a decimal:"))
portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
months = 0
while current_saving <= portion_down_payment:
    if months % 6 !=1:
        current_saving = current_saving * 0.04 /12 + annual_salary/12 * portion_saved + current_saving
        months +=1
    else:
        annual_salary = annual_salary*(1+semi_annual_raise)
        current_saving = current_saving * 0.04 /12 + annual_salary/12 * portion_saved + current_saving
        months +=1
    
print(months)
```

This is my own run and sample test provided by an official document by MIT OpenCourseWare.

[image]

My own run
[image]

[image]

Please help me, thank you! I will get to interact as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the computation of every 6 month with the modulo. What you are doing is that you increase the salary everytime the month is in the form `6n + 1`. Which means you increase the salary on month 1, 7, 13 etc. (as your index starts at zero, you are increasing the salary after the first month).
So you have a raise too early and the other ones too late.

**Note:** You have the same code in you `if` and `else` part, put it outside for easier to read and maintain code.

```py
while current_saving <= portion_down_payment:
    # Apply the raise every time the month is a multiple of 6 (as you start from 0, you need the +1 here)
    if (months + 1) % 6 == 0:
        annual_salary = annual_salary*(1+semi_annual_raise)
    current_saving = current_saving * 0.04 /12 + annual_salary/12 * portion_saved + current_saving
    months +=1
```